# How to exit a C++ program if the declaration of a global variable throws an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, global-variables

I have a program where I need an instance of a class to be global (it is const),  but the constructor of the class requires a particular text file to exist (if it doesn't exist the program should quit).  If I throw an exception in the constructor it cannot be caught outside of the constructor because I can't have a try{ }catch{ } block outside of a function which I need to do in order for the instance of the class to be global.

How can I use exceptions to ensure memory is still cleaned up if the declaration of the global variable throws an exception?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by a global cleaning method? I spent a while trying to find such a thing earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't worry about the memory.

If the constructor of a global throws, your program isn't staying around long enough for it to matter, it's already on the way out.

Next, if you really insist, just make sure the destructors of all global objects are also able to destroy all associated resources, as they should be able to do for RAII to work anyway.

And if an object is only partially constructed, all dtors corresponding to successfully completed member (and base) ctors will be called, so it shouldn't be too hard to make sure your ctor does not leak anything on throwing.

Comment: Thanks, just did a quick check to see that if I called `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` when the exception was thrown the destructors of previously declared globals would be called (and they are) :)